# why symmetricDS community edition ask for license key?

Tags: symmetricds

i already downloaded symmetric-3.5.19-server.zip for community edition
after i following this step http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.5/html-single/user-guide.html#tutorial-install
and finished it, it showing a message Missing license key. Please install a license key before using the web console.
is the community edition require to buy a license?

Answer (score 2):

SymmetricDS community edition will not ask for license,you are actually using SymmetricDS Pro edition which you can acquired trial 30 days license key from [here](http://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/download?download=1). you have to provide your email for them to give you license key.

the actual symmetricds community edition is like what Austin Brougher have provide at his [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/symmetricds/files/).

Answer (score 1):

The community edition found on symmetricds.org does not have a web console. You must have the Pro version which can be found at jumpmind.com.

You can get the latest open source version here.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/symmetricds/files/

Comment: oh thanks, but how to run symmetricds community edition if i want to use for open source?
should i try to another program?

Comment: btw i'm using win 7 and firebird database

Comment: sorry before i have another problem, i run with cmd install_service.bat
and its crashed with message
Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 3.3.9 has stopped working
can someone help me please..